# JButton con bordes redondos

Tags: java, netbeans

Mi duda en este momento es si existe algún método o clase predefinida en java para poder crear un botón con los bordes redondos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `JButton` en realidad tiene bordes redondos, lo que puedes realizar es aumentar el radio del angúlo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como propuesta esta clase:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

class RoundedBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;

    RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

Creas tu botón y defines en la propiedad Border la clase con el radio deseado:

```
//Crea boton.
 JButton myButton = new JButton("my button");
 //Define 40 como Radio.
 myButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(40));
```